# Phrase for being robbed/deprived of my money

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

Here is the situation: I provide services to a client through a company's platform. The company provides a software that keeps track of the amount of time I spend and automatically bills the client accordingly. Recently I found that due to a technical problem in the software, it was under-billing the amount of time and in the past few years, this has cost me thousands of $$. I talked to the company about it and they are now advising me to claim this money from the client directly trying to convince him about the issue.

I'm now writing to the company and want to express that he would find this claim deceitful. What would be the proper words to express my feeling? I'm considering words like underhanded, deceiving etc.

Also what would be the proper word or phrase for my feeling of being robbed and deprived of my money?

Comment: Just to be clear, *who* would find this claim deceitful?  Your clients whom you have under-billed, or the company who wrote the software?   Typically you'll find that the software has a EULA that specifically disclaims it being fit for any particular use and limits liability to the purchase price of the software.

Comment: @Jim: Yeah, I mean the client would find the claim deceitful.

Comment: *deceitful* means that they would think you are lying to them.  Why would they think that if you explain the situation? I can understand that they might think that it was your mistake and that they've "already paid you" and might expect you to "eat" the difference, but I wouldn't think you were lying to me.

Comment: @Jim: I probably want to agree with you here. Deceitful is not the proper word to express it. This is more on the lines that you have noted. But then that is exactly why I'm here; I want to know a more proper phrase or word for that feeling of the client (that they have already paid and that this is not their responsibility etc).

Comment: @Jim: It can be taken as deceitful only in the sense that this is a huge claim (in terms of $$) that the client has no means of verifying.

Comment: I think you need to keep all the words you're looking for out of the letter (at least the first one you send them). Just present your case. I'd be considering words like *lawyer* to use in a letter sent to the company that provided the software. The client is not responsible for your botched equipment. Client needs a letter from the 'company' (good luck having them cop to it, that would probably make them liable).

Comment: This is an issue more suited for legal/financial advice. I completely agree with @Mazura that this is a matter for lawyers to address. You are understandably upset, but you definitely need to have a thorough review (by said lawyer, or similar) of any agreements you have with the intermediary company, and I would absolutely avoid escalating the matter (with either party) via any sort of accusatory wording.

Comment: @Michael_B: I do understand client's position. I do agree that this would be a shock for him and probably unkind too. I am also not blaming him for anything. No one but the company should bear the burden here, but as someone already mentioned, I don't know if those EULA terms have left any option for me to claim it legally.

Comment: You might be able to ask Law.SE to take a look at the EULA, but they CANNOT give you legal advice. But I will ;) You say *you* found an error. Threaten 'company' that you're going to notify their other customers about this error and form a class action suit (but you'd *better* be sure {you don't want to get sued for slander}, and really you should seek paid legal advice, but unless we're talking about ~100k, it's prob best to let it go). Is the money (it will cost you) and your time worth it?

Comment: @Mazura: The unreported time sample I have seen (and I have seen it only last week) has missed about 0.6 hours from a total of 3.7 hours, which means about 15% loss. If I take that figure as global average, this would translate to about 10k-15k loss over the entire period. So according to your number, this is something not fat enough to invest my efforts after?

Comment: The only time I've been in court was on field trip. Well, and one other time... *cough*. I don't know how much it could cost; I've never retained a lawyer. Keep in mind that if 3.7h is on the low side of an average work day, that 15% could become 4% real quick (if say, it's cutting off the start and end times a little, or something). I guess I'd also be weary of a lawyer that says, sure we can do that, sign here... so I'm not sure what to tell you. I'd say if it's less than 10k, absolutely not (you ain't gonna see any of that money after all the fees, and w\e you do see isn't worth your time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have suffered a **financial loss** [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/financial+loss)

> nonpayment, nonremittal, default - loss resulting from failure of a debt to be paid

If you came to me claiming that I owed you money when I paid the bill you sent me I wouldn't see that as deceitful so much as incompetent.  A perception that would likely harm your business further.

If you are not the only client this happened to then you may have grounds for a class action suit.  But like Danny Devito said in Other People's Money, "Lawyers are like nuclear weapons.  I gotta have mine because they have theirs.  But once you use them they screw everything up."

The smart play is convince them you're willing and prepared to go to court so they will offer a decent settlement.  How to do that without blowing more money then you stand to gain goes well beyond what I'm competent to advise you.

> Also what would be the proper word or phrase for my feeling of being robbed and deprived of my money?

If the offending party had taken your money I'd say cheated.  But since all they did was fail to perform the job you trusted them to do I'd say the better word would be betrayed.

Comment: Hmmm... I like that word "betrayed". It conveys my feelings and their incompetence quite comprehensively. About your other point, literally thousands of people use that software, so I'll see how we can proceed in this regard.